# CSS Not Selector for all children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply a style to all **li** items as long as that item is not anywhere in a container with a class of .k-widget

```
.c-w1 ol li :not(.k-widget) { list-style: decimal outside; }
```

However the style continues to be applied. The **.k-widget** is on a div that contain divs that contain the actual **li** I don't want styled.

```
<div class="k-widget">
   <Lots of Things>
      <li> ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be something like that:

```
div:not(.k-widget) .c-w1 ol li {
    list-style: decimal outside;
}
```

Of course the `:not()` has to be applied on the div which is before the li [as allready stated by Marijke Luttekes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18087368/983992).

Also have a look at [caniuse for browser support of css3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Another possibility would be to tell the `.k-widget` contents to inherit its styles with `list-style: inherit;`. So you can override it without using a specific value and adding redundance to your styles:

```
div .c-w1 ol li {
    list-style: decimal outside;
}

div.k-widget .c-w1 ol li {
    list-style: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the list style is applied to any item inside a `li` that does not have the class `.k-widget` applied. If I understand your problem correctly, you can easily fix this by placing the statement `:not(.k-widget)` before `li`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `:not()` selector on a parent will match if any parent matches, and since all `li` elements are within both `body` and `html`, all `li` elements will match.

I would recommend constructing two styles, one overriding the other.

```
 .c-w1 ol li { list-style: decimal outside; }
```

And

```
 .c-w1 .k-widget ol li { override style here }
```

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of overriding styles unless completely necessary (since it might just mean you have wrongly structured your code). I liked the `:not()` approach. This answer is not wrong, though.